# Reflect live updae of API in UI without refreshing screen

Tags: angularjs

I am making a web app in which I have a section which has an input field. Anything that is submitted through the input field gets posted to an API. So when you land on that screen you see all the previous inputs made. What I am not able to figure out is and the thing I want to achieve is that when someone submits a new input it doesn't reflect in UI until and unless you go back and come back to the screen. I want that as soon as you send an input the input string should be reflected in the UI. How can this be done using AngularJS?

Comment: First add your code so we can have a look, also this is probably an update of your model issue, you have to update your model to get instant change on your UI

Comment: I dont have any code ready for the matter. Just a basic UI which shows a list like TODO list and an input field. to add like a new todo. Basic html and angular post method. Just when I submit new entry, i have to refresh to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options, at a very basic level they are:

1) The first is to re-query all the list when the item is saved:

```
api.save(newPost).then(() => getAllPosts());
```

2) You can return the recently saved post and add it to the list:

```
api.save(newPost).then((saved) => $scope.posts.push(saved));
```

You'll need to handle all the unwrapping (etc) based on how you're making the calls.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me with the idea of what I had to do. Thanks again.